# Pasting attributes in FCPX- succeeds, but does not list pasted attributes for new clip?

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

When I paste attributes (color correction), it has the desired effect, but then when I click on the clip I pasted to, the inspector does not show that the attribute has been pasted.

For example, I color correct clip A by increasing midtone exposure by 20 points. When I paste the "color correction 1" attribute on clip B, that clip will have the desired look, but in the inspector it will have midtone exposure at "0", rather than "20". Why is that?